# Java Text Field Not Updating

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a calculator program where click a button and then it would add to the Java Text Field(Not the Java Text Area), and I use the ActionEvent e to figure out the action. Then using the actionCommand where I get the actionListener I try to add the text to the java text field. And somehow it is not updating into the java text field. Is this a problem with repaint or something.

Here's my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String actionCommand = "";
    ArrayList<Integer> numberSet1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numberSet2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel();
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    int number1 = 0;
    int number2 = 0;
    JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
    JButton btn1;
    JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    public Calculator() {
        super("Calculator");
        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(600,600);
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField("This is the text field");
        jtf.setSize(getWidth(),50);
        add(jtf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jtf.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        jtf.setEditable(false);
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        Font myFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 32);
        jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
        JButton butt0 = new JButton("0");
        butt0.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt1 = new JButton("1");
        butt1.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt2 = new JButton("2");
        butt2.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt3 = new JButton("3");
        butt3.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt4 = new JButton("4");
        butt4.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt5 = new JButton("5");
        butt5.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt6 = new JButton("6");
        butt6.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt7 = new JButton("7");
        butt7.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt8 = new JButton("8");
        butt8.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt9 = new JButton("9");
        butt9.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt10 = new JButton("+");
        butt10.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt11 = new JButton("-");
        butt11.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt12 = new JButton("*");
        butt12.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt13 = new JButton("/");
        butt13.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt14 = new JButton("=");
        butt14.setFont(myFont);
        JButton butt15 = new JButton("clear");
        butt15.setFont(myFont);
        butt1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt2.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt3.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt4.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt5.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt6.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt7.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt8.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt9.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt10.setBackground(Color.red);
        butt11.setBackground(Color.red);
        butt12.setBackground(Color.red);
        butt13.setBackground(Color.red);
        butt14.setBackground(Color.red);
        butt15.setBackground(Color.red);
        butt0.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butt10.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
        butt11.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
        butt12.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
        butt13.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
        butt14.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
        butt15.setForeground(Color.lightGray);
        jp.add(butt0);
        jp.add(butt1);
        jp.add(butt2);
        jp.add(butt3);
        jp.add(butt4);
        jp.add(butt5);
        jp.add(butt6);
        jp.add(butt7);
        jp.add(butt8);
        jp.add(butt9);
        jp.add(butt10);
        jp.add(butt11);
        jp.add(butt12);
        jp.add(butt13);
        jp.add(butt14);
        jp.add(butt15);
        butt0.addActionListener(this);
        butt0.setActionCommand("0");
        butt1.addActionListener(this);
        butt1.setActionCommand("1");
        butt2.addActionListener(this);
        butt2.setActionCommand("2");
        butt3.addActionListener(this);
        butt3.setActionCommand("3");
        butt4.addActionListener(this);
        butt4.setActionCommand("4");
        butt5.addActionListener(this);
        butt5.setActionCommand("5");
        butt6.addActionListener(this);
        butt6.setActionCommand("6");
        butt7.addActionListener(this);
        butt7.setActionCommand("7");
        butt8.addActionListener(this);
        butt8.setActionCommand("8");
        butt9.addActionListener(this);
        butt9.setActionCommand("9");
        butt10.addActionListener(this);
        butt10.setActionCommand("+");
        butt11.addActionListener(this);
        butt11.setActionCommand("-");
        butt12.addActionListener(this);
        butt12.setActionCommand("*");
        butt13.addActionListener(this);
        butt13.setActionCommand("/");
        butt14.addActionListener(this);
        butt14.setActionCommand("=");
        butt15.addActionListener(this);
        butt15.setActionCommand("clear");

        add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        actionCommand  = e.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println("Clicked" + actionCommand);
        jtf.setText(actionCommand);
    }

    public void phase1() {
        while (!(actionCommand.equals("+")) || !(actionCommand.equals("-")) || !(actionCommand.equals("*")) || !(actionCommand.equals("/")) || !(actionCommand.equals("clear")) || !(actionCommand.equals("="))) {
            numberSet1.add(Integer.parseInt(actionCommand));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < numberSet1.size(); i++) {

        }
    }

    public void phase2() {

    }
    public int calculations() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different JTextField variables that are both named `jtf`.

The first is an instance variable, which you have declared with `JTextField jtf = new JTextField();`, and is accessible from anywhere in the class.

The second is a local variable, which you have declared with `JTextField jtf = new JTextField("This is the text field");`, and is only accessible in the constructor of `Calculator`.

The problem is that the second `jtf` (the local variable) is being added to the UI, while the first `jtf` (the instance variable) is what's being updated by the action event.

To fix this, change this (near the top of the class): `JTextField jtf = new JTextField();`

to this: `JTextField jtf;`

And then change this (in the constructor):

`JTextField jtf = new JTextField("This is the text field");`

to this: `jtf = new JTextField("This is the text field");`

Then, you'll only have one `jtf` variable (which will be an instance variable), and your action event should work.

Comment: No worries! It's always the little things that trip you up :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line:

```
JTextField jtf = new JTextField("This is the text field");
```

from constructor. 
The first is an instance variable, JTextField e.g. jtf  is accessible from anywhere in the class.